# Trouble inserting list items by chunk into SQLITE insert query from CSV files - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to insert data by chunks from a CSV files in the folder, but I cannot get the SQLITE insert query right. I was able to perform it without the lists, so I know that the data is correct.
However when I use the lists I get the error: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 10, and there are 65 supplied.`
Any ideas?

```
import csv, sqlite3, time, os

def chunks(data, rows=10000):
    data = list(data)
    for i in range(0, len(data), rows):
       yield data[i:i+rows]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    datab = 'MYDB'
    con=sqlite3.connect(datab+'.db')
    con.text_factory = str  
    cur = con.cursor()
    koko = 'C:\\MYFOLDER\\'
    print(koko)
    directory = koko 
    print(directory)

    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        for searchfile, csvfile, csvcolumn, tablecolumn, table, valuemark, valcsvcolumn  in zip(['USR02_FINAL.csv'],
                                ['USR02_FINAL.csv'],
                                [['SYS,MANDT, BNAME, GLTGV, GLTGB, USTYP, CLASS, UFLAG, ERDAT, TRDAT']],
                                [['SYS,MANDT, BNAME, GLTGV2, GLTGB2, USTYP, CLASS, UFLAG, ERDAT2, TRDAT2']],                    
                              ['USR_02_ALL_RAW2'],
                              [['?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?']],
                              [['SYS,MANDT, BNAME, GLTGV, GLTGB, USTYP, CLASS, UFLAG, ERDAT, TRDAT']]):

                        if file.endswith(searchfile):
                                fileinsert = directory + '\\' + csvfile
                                csvData = csv.reader(open(fileinsert, "rt"))

                                divData = chunks(csvData) # divide into 10000 rows each

                                for chunk in divData:
                                    cur.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')

                                    for csvcolumn in chunk:

                                        print(searchfile, csvfile, csvcolumn, tablecolumn, table, valuemark, valcsvcolumn)

                                        cur.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO """ + table +""" ("""+ ', '.join(tablecolumn) +""") VALUES ("""+ ', '.join(valuemark)+""")""",( ', '.join(valcsvcolumn))) 
                                        cur.execute('COMMIT')
```

Comment: Can you give us the `chunks` function? Did you look what chunked data look like, e.g. by chunking into smaller pieces and printing it?

Comment: Yes, it prints out the values (represented by the quotation mark correctly). This is the 
`print` of the query :  `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO AGR_AGRS_ALL2 (SYS, MANDT, AGR_NAME, CHILD_AGR, ATTRIBUTES) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?), SYS, MANDT, AGR_NAME, CHILD_AGR, ATTRIBUTES`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the loops:

```py
for chunk in divData:
  # ...
  for csvcolumn in chunk:
    # ...
    ...join(valcsvcolumn)
```

I see that you only use `csvcolumn` in the `print`, but not in the insert statement; it's using `valcsvcolumn` which is an unrelated thing. Probably this is the problem.